# How do I display names starting with specific character in BQ

Tags: google-bigquery

How do I display the country names starting with A,G and E?

```
#standardSQL
with table1 as(
select "America" as country_name union all
select "Germany" as country_name union all
select "England" as country_name union all
select "Nauru" as country_name union all
select "Brunei" as country_name union all
select "Kiribati" as country_name union all
select "Djibouti" as country_name union all
select "Malta" as country_name
)
select * from table1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH table1 AS(
  SELECT "America" AS country_name UNION ALL
  SELECT "Germany" AS country_name UNION ALL
  SELECT "England" AS country_name UNION ALL
  SELECT "Nauru" AS country_name UNION ALL
  SELECT "Brunei" AS country_name UNION ALL
  SELECT "Kiribati" AS country_name UNION ALL
  SELECT "Djibouti" AS country_name UNION ALL
  SELECT "Malta" AS country_name
)
SELECT *
FROM table1
ORDER BY CASE 
  WHEN LOWER(SUBSTR(country_name, 1, 1)) IN ('a', 'g', 'e') 
  THEN CONCAT(' ', country_name) ELSE country_name 
END
```

expected output is

```sql
Row country_name     
1   America  
2   England  
3   Germany  
4   Brunei   
5   Djibouti     
6   Kiribati     
7   Malta    
8   Nauru
```

In case if you need ONLY those country

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH table1 AS(
  SELECT "America" AS country_name UNION ALL
  SELECT "Germany" AS country_name UNION ALL
  SELECT "England" AS country_name UNION ALL
  SELECT "Nauru" AS country_name UNION ALL
  SELECT "Brunei" AS country_name UNION ALL
  SELECT "Kiribati" AS country_name UNION ALL
  SELECT "Djibouti" AS country_name UNION ALL
  SELECT "Malta" AS country_name
)
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE LOWER(SUBSTR(country_name, 1, 1)) IN ('a', 'g', 'e')
```

or

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH table1 AS(
  SELECT "America" AS country_name UNION ALL
  SELECT "Germany" AS country_name UNION ALL
  SELECT "England" AS country_name UNION ALL
  SELECT "Nauru" AS country_name UNION ALL
  SELECT "Brunei" AS country_name UNION ALL
  SELECT "Kiribati" AS country_name UNION ALL
  SELECT "Djibouti" AS country_name UNION ALL
  SELECT "Malta" AS country_name
)
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(country_name, r'(?i)^(a|g|e)')
```

both above returns:

```sql
Row country_name     
1   America  
2   Germany  
3   England
```

Comment: do you mean America, Germany, England in that exact order ? cause otherwise it is there in answer

Comment: or do you mean just display ONLY countries started with a, e, g - please clarify

Comment: only exactly that 3 countries

Comment: consider voting up the answer :o)